# Is there a way to set RequestBody when sending http request using SimpleHttp (org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp)?

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus, rest-client, keycloak-spi

My question is :

Is there a way to set RequestBody when sending http request using SimpleHttp (org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp)?

Why I am using SimpleHttp?

I am writing a custom service provider (SPI) to be plugged in Keycloak version 20.0.0.
I need to use any rest client to send HTTP requests, but I encountered lots of difficulties doing so thanks to the new Quarkus-based version of Keycloak.

After a lot of searches, this [post](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/trying-to-send-http-rest-request-from-keycloak-x-user-storage-spi-to-an-external-api/15325/2) form Keycloak community was helpful. it suggests using SimpleHttp utility which does not require any external libraries.

Tried resteasy-client before SimpleHttp
Expected the same behavior on the previous Keycloak version, but it is now different, you need to mention all external libraries in META-INF/services. but even this is not working. (reateasy is no longer included with the new codebase)

This is why I started looking for different rest clients.

Answer (score 0):

I found a field called ==> "json"
turns out it is the request body.